# Not able to open file(pdf/doc) from my app after downloading in android

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I am downloading file(pf/doc) from url. I have read & write permission as well & providers also defined in manifest & provider_path also.

File successfully downloaded in my phone "Download" folder. But when i try to open file with following code it gives me an error `"this file could not be accessed. check your connection or make the file name shorter"`

```
var attachmentUri: Uri? = attachmentUri
        if (attachmentUri != null) {
            if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE == attachmentUri.scheme) { // FileUri - Convert it to contentUri.
                val file = File(attachmentUri.path)
                attachmentUri =
                    FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,  context.applicationContext
                        .packageName + ".provider", file)
            }
            context.grantUriPermission(context.packageName, attachmentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            val openAttachmentIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            openAttachmentIntent.setDataAndType(attachmentUri, attachmentMimeType)
            openAttachmentIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            openAttachmentIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            try {
                context.startActivity(openAttachmentIntent)
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to open file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
```

attachmentUri -  `content://com.hello.provider/external_files/Download/ac_xyz-2.pdf`  I am also not able to open doc file as well.

File download code :

```
if (url != null && !url.isEmpty()) {
                val uri = Uri.parse(url)
                activity.registerReceiver(
                    attachmentDownloadCompleteReceive, IntentFilter(
                        DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE
                    )
                )
                val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
                request.setMimeType(getMimeType(uri.toString()))
                request.setTitle(fileName)
                request.setDescription("Downloading attachment..")
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)
                val dm = activity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
                dm.enqueue(request)
            }
```

Is there any way to solve this error ?

Comment: You should have started your post telling us who downloaded that file and how. Who decided that it should be stored in that path?

Comment: After that you should show how you build up attachmentUri . At the moment we have no idea what you do. Also tell Android version of used device.

Comment: Further it is unclear which app gave you mentioned error.

Comment: Added download file code. I have default app adobe acrobat to open pdf

Comment: Android version!

Comment: Android version is 10

Comment: On an Android 10 device you have no access to that file (well unless..). Check for yourself with. File.canRead() and File.canWrite().

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build up an uri using a file provider for a file in Download folder.

Not needed.

Register a broadcast receiver for action download complete and you will get notified when the download is ready.

Also you will get then a nice uri from the DownloadManager which you can use in an action view intent for a pdf reader.

Comment: I am already following this things. I have register broadcast receiver. I am using    val downloadLocalUri =
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI)) to get url from download manager

Comment: Ok. I see now. But then why are you messing around with your file provider on that uri? Makes no sense. Use it as it is.

Comment: Because i am getting uri like file://storage/0/download/as.pdf & i can not open directly this file ! Thats why i am converting this into content uri

Comment: Aha.. I see. That never happened to me. Then please post your broadcast receiver code too. Like to have a look. But.. realize..if you cannot directly open that file it makes no sense to let your file provider try to open and serve it as of course it cannot open it then too.